# Returning &str from env::var while parsing env::vars

Tags: rust, environment-variables

I am trying to return `&str` as a default value in an if statement

```rust
use std::env;
fn main() {

    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let value: &str = if args.len() < 3 {
        match env::var("DEFAULT") {
            Ok(val) => val.as_str(),
            Err(_) => "default",
        }
    } else { args[1].as_str()};

}
```

This fails with

```
error[E0597]: `val` does not live long enough
 --> tmp.rs:8:24
  |
6 |     let value: &str = if args.len() < 3 {
  |         ----- borrow later stored here
7 |         match env::var("DEFAULT") {
8 |             Ok(val) => val.as_str(),
  |                ---     ^^^        - `val` dropped here while still borrowed
  |                |       |
  |                |       borrowed value does not live long enough
  |                binding `val` declared here

error: aborting due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
```

How would I fix this? Moving `env::var` outside the if statement does not help.

(Title is kinda badly formulated, feel free to update it.)

Comment: Why not simply use `String`?

Comment: Is it standard to use `String`? I could. Use `args[1].to_owned()` and later transform with `let default = default.as_str();` but it seemed unintuitive to call after the fact.

Comment: Note that [`String` derefs to `&str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#deref-methods-str), so you almost never need to call `as_str` explicitly: if `value` has type `String`, simply using `&value` will work whenever you need a `&str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request does not make much sense on its face, because `env::var` always returns a copy of the actual environment variable (and once that's validated and decoded). `val` is the owner of that value, there's nobody else keeping it alive for you.

Hence the message: by not keeping a handle on `val`, you're letting it go out of scope and be dropped, thus invalidating any reference you would have taken.

Now there are mutiple ways to handle this:

1. Just use `String`, convert `default` to a `String`, and pop the relevant value out of the `args`

   e.g.

   ```
    use std::env;
    fn main() {
        let mut args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
        let value = if args.len() < 3 {
            match env::var("DEFAULT") {
                Ok(val) => val,
                Err(_) => "default".to_string(),
            }
        } else {
            args.remove(1)
        };
    }
   ```

   That avoids the reference part, no reference, no issue with not keeping the source alive.

   You could even pop the values out of `std::env::Args` by hand: it's an exact size iterator, so you don't need to collect it to a vec to know how many values it contains, you can ask it upfront.
2. Use `Cow`, that lets you unify / abstract over `String` and `&str`:

   ```
    use std::borrow::Cow;
    use std::env;
    fn main() {
        let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
        let value: Cow<'_, str> = if args.len() < 3 {
            match env::var("DEFAULT") {
                Ok(val) => val.into(),
                Err(_) => "default".into(),
            }
        } else {
            args[1].as_str().into()
        };
    }
   ```

   That works around the reference, by abstracting over owned / reference entirely.
3. Stow the String in a function-local variable before taking a reference to *that*:

   ```
    use std::env;
    fn main() {
        let env;

        let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
        let value = if args.len() < 3 {
            match env::var("DEFAULT") {
                Ok(val) => {
                    env = val;
                    &env
                },
                Err(_) => "default",
            }
        } else {
            &args[1]
        };
    }
   ```

   That solves the reference by keeping its source alive.